# How to suppress calculation process infomation and only keep calculation result in R markdown HTML?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r,message=FALSE}
library(mirt)
set.seed(12345)
a <- matrix(abs(rnorm(15,1,.3)), ncol=1)
d <- matrix(rnorm(15,0,.7),ncol=1)
itemtype <- rep('2PL', nrow(a))
N <- 1000
dataset1 <- simdata(a, d, N, itemtype)
dataset2 <- simdata(a, d, N, itemtype, mu = .1, sigma = matrix(1.5))
dat <- rbind(dataset1, dataset2)
group <- c(rep('D1', N), rep('D2', N))
models <- 'F1 = 1-15'

mod_configural <- multipleGroup(dat, models, group = group)

coef(mod_configural )
```
````

Run above `Rmd` script and `knit to HTML`,I will get caculation result output as:

```
## $D1
## $Item_1
##        a1     d g u
## par 1.071 0.524 0 1
## 
## $Item_2
##        a1      d g u
## par 1.217 -0.699 0 1
```

The problem is calculation process also output in HTML, such as:

```
## 
Iteration: 1, Log-Lik: -18088.494, Max-Change: 0.37763
Iteration: 2, Log-Lik: -17943.205, Max-Change: 0.18868
```

Then my HTML will become very long, hard to read.I tried to use `message=FALSE` but doesn't work.
How to suppress or fold those information in HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is very simple and has nothing to do with `RMD`.

```
mod_configural <- multipleGroup(dat, models, group = group, verbose = FALSE)
```

When you have a look at the [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mirt/mirt.pdf) (p. 95) of the package, the `verbose` option is solution.